# Does php mysql disconnect really disconnect?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with MySQL timeouts in my 24/7 PHP shell script.

I was under impression that Pear DB DB::connect() would create new handle but this does not seem to be the case. DB::connect() actually returns "server has gone away" error even when used in a loop for five times.

I now added db->disconnect() and unset( $db) to the script before the DB::connect(). Will this cause the underlying mysql module to free the resources before connect (localhost) ? If not then I don't see other options than using the proprietary new_link.

Comment: Why are you connecting to a database five times? Do you have five different databases? (why not just open the connection once before the loop and then use that connection until you're done)

Comment: @TerrySeidler It just tries to connect up to five times in a loop until gives up. THe connection always returns the error "has gone away".

Comment: oooh... I see. Makes more sense now :}

Comment: Please check process list on your mysql server. How many connections are there? How many concurent connection can your server handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Inconclusive.

I made sample php script to connect twice with same settings, run mysql_close() and then third connection.
I also ran tcpdump in another window.

On the first few runs there was some traffic to the server on subsequent connects. Then this traffic disappeared.

Now the result is that without mysql_close() the mysql_connect() indeed uses the previous connection and there is zero traffic on subsequent mysql_connect().

When running mysql_close() the dump would indicate the TCP connection is closed.

On the third connect the connection is again established from the start.

```
13:37:57.842598 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: S 3281731243:3281731243(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 503312235 0,nop,wscale 7>
13:37:57.887534 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58772: S 1293434507:1293434507(0) ack 3281731244 win 5792 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 3402066848 503312235,nop,wscale 7>
13:37:57.887639 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: . ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503312245 3402066848>
13:37:57.932750 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58772: P 1:61(60) ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402066859 503312245>
13:37:57.932843 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: . ack 61 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503312256 3402066859>
13:37:57.935983 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: P 1:62(61) ack 61 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503312258 3402066859>
13:37:57.981130 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58772: . ack 62 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402066871 503312258>
13:37:57.981181 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58772: P 61:72(11) ack 62 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402066871 503312258>
13:37:58.017172 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: . ack 72 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503312279 3402066871>

at 13:38:01 there was the second mysql connection

at 13:38:04 now the mysql_close():    
13:38:03.989796 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: P 62:67(5) ack 72 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503313772 3402066871>
13:38:03.989844 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: F 67:67(0) ack 72 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503313772 3402066871>
13:38:04.034818 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58772: F 72:72(0) ack 68 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402068385 503313772>
13:38:04.034920 IP 192.168.1.1.58772 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: . ack 73 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503313783 3402068385>

at 13:38:07 the third connection after mysql_close(). Afterwards script exits and mysql connection is closed.
13:38:06.995120 IP 192.168.1.1.58773 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: S 3287179963:3287179963(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 503314523 0,nop,wscale 7>
13:38:07.035065 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58773: S 1439831970:1439831970(0) ack 3287179964 win 5792 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 3402069136 503314523,nop,wscale 7>
13:38:07.035166 IP 192.168.1.1.58773 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: . ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503314533 3402069136>
13:38:07.075107 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58773: P 1:61(60) ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402069146 503314533>
13:38:07.075188 IP 192.168.1.1.58773 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: . ack 61 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503314543 3402069146>
13:38:07.075437 IP 192.168.1.1.58773 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: P 1:62(61) ack 61 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503314543 3402069146>
13:38:07.115123 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58773: . ack 62 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402069156 503314543>
13:38:07.115178 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58773: P 61:72(11) ack 62 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402069156 503314543>
13:38:07.115821 IP 192.168.1.1.58773 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: P 62:67(5) ack 72 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503314553 3402069156>
13:38:07.115844 IP 192.168.1.1.58773 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: F 67:67(0) ack 72 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503314553 3402069156>
13:38:07.155524 IP 192.168.2.2.mysql > 192.168.1.1.58773: F 72:72(0) ack 68 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3402069166 503314553>
13:38:07.155606 IP 192.168.1.1.58773 > 192.168.2.2.mysql: . ack 73 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 503314563 3402069166>
```

And the script:

```
<?php

output( "starting");
$start = microtime(true);
$res = mysql_connect('192.168.2.2','user','pass');
if( $res === FALSE )
        die(output("SQL error on connect\n"));
output(sprintf("Connect took: %.3f", (microtime(true)-$start)));

output("sleep 3");
sleep(3);

$start = microtime(true);
$res = mysql_connect('192.168.2.2','user','pass');
if( $res === FALSE )
        die(output("SQL error on connect\n"));
output(sprintf("Connect took: %.3f", (microtime(true)-$start)));

output("sleep 3");
sleep(3);

output("closing");
mysql_close( $res );

output("sleep 3");
sleep(3);

$start = microtime(true);
$res = mysql_connect('192.168.2.2','user','pass');
if( $res === FALSE )
        die(output("SQL error on connect\n"));
output(sprintf("Connect took: %.3f", (microtime(true)-$start)));

output("all done");
exit;

function output($str)
{
        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." ".$str."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php):

> Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections
>   to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end
>   of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests
>   a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection
>   cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new
>   connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting
>   in a faster web application.

This is know as a connection pool. Connections are made using a connection pool. Even if you create a new connection, it is taken from the pool and given to you.

Do **not** close connections, as it will downgrade performance, and bring you no benefits at all.